# Replace multi-level relationship in Entity Framework Core 6 vs 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following model

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public int IdParent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FirstChild> FirstChild{ get; set; } = new List<FirstChild>();
}

public partial class FirstChild
{
    public int IdFirstChild { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SecondChild> SecondChild { get; set; } = new List<SecondChild>();
}

public partial class SecondChild 
{
    public int IdSecondChild  { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ThirdChild> ThirdChild{ get; set; } = new List<ThirdChild>();
}

public partial class ThirdChild
{
    public int IdThirdChild { get; set; }

    public String SomeProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

I update `Parent` with all it's relationships it this way :

```
var parentDB = _context.Parent.Single(x => x.IdParent == {id})
.Include(x => x.FirstChild)
.ThenInclude(x => x.SecondChild)
.ThenInclude(x => x.ThirdChild);

parentDb.FirstChild = {newCollectionValuesList}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

This works with EF Core 6 :

- If in `{newCollectionValuesList}`, there is an element that already exists in `parentDb.FirstChild` (same ID), it get updated (with all its hierarchy)
- If if does not exists, it will be added
- If it exists but was not specified in `{newCollectionValuesList}`, it get deleted

When I upgraded to EF Core 7, I started to have this error :

> The instance of entity type 'SecondChild' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{IdSecondChild: XXXX}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

I added `.AsNoTracking()` in the query to resolve this, but the deletion does not work (when `{newCollectionValuesList}` does not contain an element that exists in the database, in does not get deleted)

I don't want to loop manually through all the relationship and manually add the conditions to update the child elements

I didn't find anything related to that in [What's new in EF7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew) nor in [Breaking changes in EF7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes) nor in previous SO questions

This is a [sample project](https://github.com/iheb719/EntityFrameworkMigration6to7) with integration tests to reproduce the problem

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] cause current code should not even compile.

Comment: This is more likely due to differences in the data than EF version. Looks like `newCollectionValuesList` contains multiple `SecondChild` instances having the same key, or one that has the same key as an already attached instance.

Comment: It's exactly the same data. I caught this error with my integration tests (no by manually testing). So the inputs are exactly the same

Comment: Why this example should not compile ?

Comment: I added a sample project to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the response in [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30135) in efcore issues in github

It's a bug that is planned for [7.0.4](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/milestone/160?closed=1).
Until then, this is a workaround :

Before selecting from the database, clear the `FirstChild` from EF change tracker

```
var existingParent = _context.Parent.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdParent == parentUpdate.IdParent);
    existingParent?.FirstChild.Clear();
    _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

var parentDB = _context.Parent.Single(x => x.IdParent == {id})
    .Include(x => x.FirstChild)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.SecondChild)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.ThirdChild);

parentDb.FirstChild = {newCollectionValuesList}


_context.SaveChanges();
```